# What is the supertype of all functions in Scala?

Tags: scala, reflection, macros, functional-programming, scala-macros

I know I can do `instanceOf` checks against `Function1` or `Function2` etc but is there a generic way to see if something is function or not (it can have arbitray number of args). I tried defining something like this:

```
type FuncType = (Any*) -> Any
```

But that did not work either. Basically I have some code that looks like this:

```
call = (name: Any, args: Any*) -> if name.isFunction then name.castAs[Function].apply(args) else name
aFunction = (name: String) => "Hello " + name
notAFunction = "Hello rick"
call(aFunction, "rick")
call(notAFunction)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this, except to go through and check each of `Function1`, `Function2`, etc. The parent of each of these traits is `AnyRef`, which won't help you to distinguish them from anything else. The `apply` method for each of these traits takes a different number of parameters, so there is no way to give them a parent that has an apply method. The closest you could probably get to what you are trying to do is:

```
def arbitraryFunction(function: AnyRef, args: Seq[Any]): Any = {
  function match {
    case f: Function1[Any, Any] => f(args(0))
    case f: Function2[Any, Any, Any] => f(args(0), args(1))
    // and so on
  }
}
```

But this is insane and dangerous and will throw exceptions at runtime if the types are wrong, e.g.

```
arbitraryFunction((x: Int) => x * 2, List("I'm a String!"))
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no general supertype for all function types.

Scala has no way to abstract over the arity of a function. However, you might look into the [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) library, which introduces something called an `HList` that you can use for abstracting the arity of functions.

However, I'm thinking that's not really what you need. It sounds like you just want to do a check like "is this a function?" You might think it's weird that there's no arity-agnostic `Function` supertype, but you'd pretty much always need to know the arity of a function if you want to do something useful with it.

Alternatively, you might be able to do something with the `curried` method on the function, which will return a `Function1`.